# FluentHibernate: how to specify join-mapped table should never be inserted into

Tags: nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following FluentNHibernate mapping:

```
public AssetMap()
    {
      Table("PRASSET");
      Id(x => x.Id).Column("PRA_RECNUM").GeneratedBy.Sequence("PRA_RECNUM_GEN");
      ...fields mapped from PRASSET table
      Join("PRSTOCK", m =>
      {
        m.Fetch.Join();
        m.Optional();
        m.KeyColumn("PRS_ASSRN");
        ...fields mapped from PRSTOCK table
      });
    }
```

As the `m.Optional()` call in the `Join` bit suggests, there may or may not be a corresponding `PRSTOCK` record.

The problem I am having is that when I save an `Asset` instance which is dirty only in respect of one of its `PRASSET`-mapped properties, and there isn't a corresponding `PRSTOCK` record, it's inserting one! This is emphatically not what I want to happen, since there should not be a corresponding `PRSTOCK` record in most cases.

Is there a tweak in the mapping configuration I can try? It would be enough at this stage just to prevent records ever being inserted into `PRSTOCK`, but ideally NHibernate should not try to update or insert `PRSTOCK` unless one of the `Asset` instance's properties mapped to `PRSTOCK` has been dirtied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join) blog post, NHibernate will always try to insert join-mapped records if the properties are not null. So I have made the appropriate properties nullable (default null) and hopefully it won't try to insert anymore.